# OS sort of Terminal in C#, trying to use process.start in terminal on C programs like gnu nano

Tags: c#, terminal, console

Ok, so I am making a sort of os but a terminal, its called Posco 2022 Minimal.. And I am trying to use process.start on cygwin or msys programs like nano, and it says "Failed to load x-term 256 color".
I am not even sure if its possible or no..

```
         string dotSlash = "nano.exe";
             try
             {
                 string[] dotslasha = dotSlash.Split(dotSlash, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                 Process process = new Process();
                     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
             
                     process.StartInfo.FileName = dotSlash;
                     process.Start();
                 if (process.HasExited == true) {
                 while (true)
                 {
                     Console.Write("Did the ported command work properly? (Y/N): ");
                     string ask = Console.ReadLine();
             
                     if (ask == "Y" || ask == "y")
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using the ported version of " + dotSlash);
                         break;
                     }
                     else if (ask == "N" || ask == "n")
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("The ports from linux may have required a dependency that wasn't available in PS (Posco Subsystem).");
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                 Console.WriteLine("E                OR : %INCO                ECT_PATH%");
             }
```

Comment: It should be possible.  The properties of you c# code (x86, 32 bit, 64 bit) has to be compatible with the app.  The app also have to be managed (c#) code.  If code is not managed than you need to use DllImport.

Comment: Yeah so how to use DllImport, its not mentioned anywhere!

Comment: do google search for "msdn c# dllimport learn"